# How to let netty channel.writeAndFlush() throws Exceptions when no TCP ACK response

Tags: java, exception, netty

I am developing an IM server with the Netty4 frame. Meanwhile I used the method named `channel.writeAndFlush()` to send messages to the client. However, when the socket of the client on the mobile phone shutting down unusually such as turning off the network connections or turning on the airplane mode on the device, the netty4 frame counld not find that the corresponding channel being inactive. Moreover, the `ChannelGroupFuture` returned by the `writeAndFlush()` method reports the sending result success with the method `ChannelGroupFuture.isSuccess()`. 
So, why the `ChannelGroupFuture` didn't return me the sending is failed without throwing any exception?

```
ChannelGroupFuture future = connectionService.sendMessageToUser(msgBase, toUid).sync();

future.addListeners(new ChannelGroupFutureListener(){

@Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelGroupFuture future)
                        throws Exception {
                    if(future.isDone() && future.isSuccess()){
                        chatMessageService.saveSentChatMessage(msgBase);
                    } else if(!future.isSuccess()){
                        chatMessageService.saveUnsentChatMessage(msgBase);
                    }
});

 public ChannelGroupFuture writeAndFlush(Object message, ChannelMatcher matcher) {
    if (message == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("message");
    }
    if (matcher == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("matcher");
    }
    if(matcher instanceof AttributeChannelMatcher){
        Map<Channel, ChannelFuture> futures = new LinkedHashMap<Channel, ChannelFuture>(1);
        AttributeChannelMatcher<T>  attributeMatcher = (AttributeChannelMatcher<T>) matcher;
        Channel c = nonServerChannelMap.get(attributeMatcher.getAttributeKeyValue());

        futures.put(c, c.writeAndFlush(safeDuplicate(message)));
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(message);
        return new DefaultChannelGroupFuture(this, futures, executor);
    }else{
        Map<Channel, ChannelFuture> futures = new LinkedHashMap<Channel, ChannelFuture>(size());

        for (Channel c :  nonServerChannelMap.values()) {
            if (matcher.matches(c)) {
                futures.put(c, c.writeAndFlush(safeDuplicate(message)));
            }
        }
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(message);
        return new DefaultChannelGroupFuture(this, futures, executor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. TCP writes are asynchronous with respect to the application. They don't wait for ACKs before they return. There is a send buffer on the sending side and a receive buffer on the receiving side. All this means that it could take several writes and quite a few seconds before you detect a broken connection.